# fullcalendar-vue views property does not react

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I want to fetch my events with the proper min and max bounds of the timeGrid calculated at server to display them with the minimum time window in local time.  However, when I set the minTime when fetching events, it does not react.  See example where time grid should start at 12:00.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>

<link href='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/core@4.1.0/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/daygrid@4.1.0/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/timegrid@4.1.0/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/core@4.1.0/main.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/daygrid@4.1.0/main.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/timegrid@4.1.0/main.js'></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/vue@4.1.0/main.umd.js"></script>

<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  new Vue({
    el: '#calendar',

    data: {
      plugins: [ window.FullCalendarTimeGrid.default ],

      views: {
        timeGrid: {
           minTime: '07:00:00',
           maxTime: '20:00:00'
        }
      }
    },

    methods: {
       fetchEvents() {
         this.views.timeGrid.minTime = '12:00:00';
         alert("minTime=" + this.views.timeGrid.minTime);
       }
    },

    template: `
       <div>
         <FullCalendar defaultView="timeGridWeek" :views="views" :plugins="plugins" :events="fetchEvents" />
       </div>`,
    });
});
</script>

<div id="calendar"></div>
```

How do I get this to react?

Comment: Your approach to setting options after initialisation of the calendar is wrong, but even if you did this in the documented way, it still wouldn't work in this particular case. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/dynamic-options says _"It is possible to dynamically set options after initalization. These option modifications will be applied to all views. It is not currently possible to set View-Specific Options in this manner."_ . Note the last sentence in particular.

Comment: You could check if this feature has already been requested, and/or if it's currently in development. If not, you could request it yourself. See https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features for details. (However since you're not using the latest version of fullCalendar, you may be stuck. I'm not part of the project but I'd guess they will probably only want to add new features to the latest version (v5) or even to the next version, if it's being planned.)

Comment: In the meantime you may have to accept the fact that in the timegrid view, the user may need to scroll to see the events, and you'll have to set min and max times statically which reflect the maximum range of event times that your application allows (e.g. maybe it's already restricted to certain hours of the day that you do business, or something).

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I'm going to upgrade to v5 in my next major release.  At least, it's good to know it's not possible, so I can quit wasting time on it.  Your workaround is what I have: a 24hr agenda view that allows everyone in the world to see events in their timezone at the expense of a lot of scrolling over whitespace.  Setting "working hours" is not useful in this case, as all events are online and accessible everywhere.

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/5224) seems to be the closest to what I want.  Added a comment.  Seems high priority in a world where all events are online.

Comment: Update: In the meantime, I have implemented a workaround that requires 2 round trips to the server.  I first report the local time zone to the server, which returns the proper time window to the client, then instantiate the calendar with those values statically.